# Setting up Python on Wine (Path, Environment Variable)

Tags: python-2.7, wine

I'm trying to get Python 2.7 running on Wine (Debian 8)

I know I need to include Python in the Windows path but I'm not sure where to find to this variable or what precisely to set it to.

I've been using wine regedit but having no luck.

I want to run a .bat file that's written in python but keep getting the error

> Can't recognise 'build_module.bat' as an internal or external command, or batch script.

Comment: so where is the build_module.bat file? can you find it?

Comment: It was in ~/.wine/drive_c/Program_Files (x86) etc. etc. I decided to give up on trying to run that compiler in Wine and converted the .bat to a .sh file, and it runs fine natively in Linux. I was worried about running into a DOS\UNIX problem but the compiler was just a simple Python script which called a bunch of other Python scripts.